# Adding a keyword search to a query function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a recipe organizer (shorter version [linked here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DUPSX5WWX5f6aAI_3SAfHvhKy_vW24iJp6Svle2D4jw/edit?usp=sharing)) for all of my recipes that I have stored in my drive, or want saved from online via link.

On the Recipe search tab I would like to adjust my current query formula to allow the use of the key word search that would search the range of Data Organizer! Column B. Currently I have the current query formula:

```
=QUERY('Data Organizer'!A2:F, "SELECT * WHERE 1=1 "&IF(A2="All Meals", ""," AND LOWER(D) = LOWER('"&A2&"') ")&IF(B2="All Types", ""," AND LOWER(E) = LOWER('"&B2&"') "))
```

I attempted the splicer tool but it wasn't user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Added formula to your [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DUPSX5WWX5f6aAI_3SAfHvhKy_vW24iJp6Svle2D4jw/edit#gid=1327077100). Please do test it out.

```
=QUERY('Data Organizer'!A2:F, "SELECT * WHERE 1=1 "&IF(A2="All Meals", ""," AND LOWER(D) = LOWER('"&A2&"') ")&IF(B2="All Types", ""," AND LOWER(E) = LOWER('"&B2&"')")&IF(D2="",""," and lower(B) matches '.*"&lower(D2)&".*'"))
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying for! Thank you!